# Is there a way to get remote peer certificate with certificate verification disabled (CERT_NONE) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using Python 3. I am using a `SSLContext` from the `ssl` library.

I would like to know how to request and get the remote peer certificate (as with `SSLSocket.getpeercert()`) but in the `CERT_NONE` mode. Currently, I get an empty dict (which is expected as per the documentation). So, can I do that without digging into private stuff?

#### N.B.

I am **not** trying to reimplement crypto. Actually, I don't need any crypto, however I need the context (and a socket) and the remote certificate (again, for information purpose, not to authenticate or actually encrypt anything).

Comment: My guess is that you are talking about getting the client certificate inside a server application?

Comment: Yes exactly! Actually I run at least two services that use cert-based authentication for clients on a TLS socket. I just figured out that there were a few illegitimate connection attempts on one of them these past few days and was very curious of who that could be and why. I was like "heck, let's just do something quick in python to check this out" but I had this problem... -_-" And there seem to be no way to disable cert check OR to enable cert fetching in CERT_REQUIRE or CERT_NONE modes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way without straying away from the default `ssl` library (which has the advantage of being there):

```
socket.getpeercert(binary_form=True)
```

gives the certificate in DER format which is good enough for what I have to do.

Afaik, returning an empty dict is to avoid blindly trusting what people send in clear text and has not been verified.

Answer (score 0):

Python/OpenSSL mix requesting the client certificate certificate with validating it:

- `CERT_NONE` (OpenSSL: `SSL_VERIFY_NONE`) will not request the certificate from the client at all. This means the client will not send a certificate.
- `CERT_REQUIRE` (OpenSSL: `SSL_VERFY_PEER|SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT`) and `CERT_OPTIONAL` (OpenSSL: `SSL_VERIFY_PEER`) will request the certificate but then also fail if the certificate could not be verified.

What you would need is to require the certificate but then have a way to handle the validation yourself and just accept all client certificates. This could be done with a custom verification callback. In OpenSSL this could be done with [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html). But unfortunately the Python [ssl library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ssl.html)  don't seem to expose the necessary interface to have your own validation callback. But it should be possible to do with [pyOpenSSL](https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl) which lets you [set your own verification callback](http://blog.san-ss.com.ar/2012/05/validating-ssl-certificate-in-python.html).